# Failed to read TIFF image file

Tags: image-processing, tiff

**Hi All**  ,

I am back with another problem.
In the production i am using an TIFF file. While loading the image, the API(3rd party library) is failing. The error code is saying that it is failing while reading/writing the file.

I am suspecting this error because of some tag which is private but could not able to verify. I used LEADTOOL TIFF TAG Editor and also IrfanView tool to see the problem. When i am re saving the file as TIFF then it is able to load and process correctly.

Can somebody point me about any tool which i can use and moreover some hint to proceed further.

Please find the TAG details(Using LEADTOOL TIFF TAG Editor ) in image below:

[image]

Thanks,
Nihal

Comment: So you would like us to tell you why your code is failing to open a TIIFF file without telling us which library you are using, without telling us the error message and without giving us the TIFF file? Mmmm... good luck.

Comment: I already explained about the error code. I want to know how can i check whether the tiff file is valid or not and also if there are some tags which are private then how can i check which tags are private.

I have also shared the tag details in the image attached above.

Comment: You can use `tiffdump` which comes with `libtiff`

Comment: It is a command line tool. Trying how to use it :)

Comment: Share the file and I'll tell you if it's valid or not. From the list of tags above, there are no private/unknown tags; they're all standard tags with normal values.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using our tools. The tags might not be enough to diagnose the problem, because it could be related to how the actual image data is stored (e.g. compression problem). However, there is something suspicious about this file's TIFF tags. The compression used appears to be LZW (5) and the pixel depth is 8 bits per pixel. There's nothing wrong with these values on their own, but Photometric Interpretation should probably be 3 not 1. With 8-bit images, there's usually a palette stored in the file and for palettized images, Photometric Interpretation should be 3.
If that's not what causes your problem, you should provide a sample image so that we could examine it more closely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you provide some email id or some contact to send the images.
Since these are some private images so i cannot post it here.
Also Can you please provide some explanation on how to diagnose or check the validity of a tiff using LEADTOOL since i only get the tag details. By looking at tags we cannot say whether the images are valid tiff or not.

Comment: As its name suggests, the TIFF tag editor only deals with TIFF tags. If you need more advanced features and detailed information about image files, our imaging toolkits for programmers can provide that. If you're a programmer there's a free evaluation edition on our website you can try. If you need help with the SDK evaluation, you can contact support@leadtools.com